# Why I feel stuffy when my dryer is running?

Tags: dryer

In the house we rent, when the dryer is running, I feel the house is stuffy.

The Washer Dryer Combo's brand is Kenmore with model number 417.93702201. I wonder if the dryer is using gas or electricity?

Is the stuffiness I feel because the dryer produces carbon monoxide?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at the [this parts digram](http://www.searspartsdirect.com/partsdirect/part-model/Kenmore-Parts/Washer-dryer-combo-Parts/Model-41793702201/0582/0152000/R0306502/00001?blt=06&prst=0&shdMod=41793702201), this model appears to be a combination washer dryer with an electric dryer, so it's not likely to be carbon monoxide.    Possibly the dryer is not correctly vented to the outside, so it is pumping warm moist air into your house.   First, make sure the lint trap on the dryer (in a slot at the bottom of the door opening) is clean.    If the dryer is vented to the outside (you should see a vent on the outside of the house near the dryer), the vent pipe may be blocked.   If it's not vented to the outside, you may want to check with your landlord to have that corrected.

Comment: Blocked vents are both likely (lint buildup) and a fire hazard. If yours appears to be blocked, make sure your landlord gets it fixed.

Comment: Put your hand over the vent and see if there's plenty of air coming out.

Comment: @Jay: Where is the vent?

Comment: @Tim: A dryer vent is a pipe that goes from the back of your dryer to somewhere outside of the house. The vent *should* be as short of possible, so it *should* go to an outside wall near where your dryer is. The vent end on the outside wall will generally have a [hood or louver like this](http://images.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=dryer+vent+hood). If your dryer does *not* have a vent to the outside, **then that is your problem**.

Comment: And make sure you clean the lint filter regularly.